# How can I query entity belonged in 2 different values in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database schema like below.

What is the SQL query to find people who belong to two different teams and are coach role in one team and player role in another team?

```
Person
-------------
Id int
Name varchar(255)

Member
-------------
Id int
PersonId int
TeamId int
Role varchar(255)

Team
-------------
Id int
TeamName varchar(255)
```

What I can come up with so far is

```
SELECT * FROM Person p
JOIN Member m
ON p.Id = m.PersonId
GROUP BY p.Id
HAVING COUNT(m.Id) > 1;
```

I am not sure this is a correct approach. Can anyone please help me with this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query you wrote will return any player which has more than one entry in the `Member` table. For example, if you had a person with a `'player'` role in 3 different teams, your query will return that person. Of course, under the assumption that this case could happen.

If you want to select people which are players in **AT LEAST** one team and coaches in **AT LEAST** one team, you could use:

```sql
SELECT p.Id, p.Name
FROM Person p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 -- select anything for checking if the row exists
              FROM Member m
              WHERE m.PersonId = p.Id
                AND m.Role LIKE 'coach')
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Member m
              WHERE m.PersonId = p.Id
                AND m.Role LIKE 'player')
```

Note that this query assumes there are no `Member` entries in which person is a player and a coach on the same team. If there are such entries, query will return those people as well.

---

For easier role management, I would also suggest moving roles to a separate table, and using their Ids for comparison instead (`m.Role = [id of the role in 'Role' table]`).